# How to make a turtle reproduce in the same patch type using hatch command in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have 31 turtles profiles that can be born in combinations of 5 habitat types. Below:

```
profile 1 needs these types of habitats: [1]
profile 2 needs these types of habitats: [2]
profile 3 needs these types of habitats: [3]
profile 4 needs these types of habitats: [4]
profile 5 needs these types of habitats: [5]
profile 6 needs these types of habitats: [1 2]
profile 7 needs these types of habitats: [1 3]
profile 8 needs these types of habitats: [1 4]
profile 9 needs these types of habitats: [1 5]
profile 10 needs these types of habitats: [2 3]
profile 11 needs these types of habitats: [2 4]
profile 12 needs these types of habitats: [2 5]
profile 13 needs these types of habitats: [3 4]
profile 14 needs these types of habitats: [3 5]
profile 15 needs these types of habitats: [4 5]
profile 16 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 3]
profile 17 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 4]
profile 18 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 5]
profile 19 needs these types of habitats: [1 3 4]
profile 20 needs these types of habitats: [1 3 5]
profile 21 needs these types of habitats: [1 4 5]
profile 22 needs these types of habitats: [2 3 4]
profile 23 needs these types of habitats: [2 3 5]
profile 24 needs these types of habitats: [2 4 5]
profile 25 needs these types of habitats: [3 4 5]
profile 26 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 3 4]
profile 27 needs these types of habitats: [1 3 4 5]
profile 28 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 4 5]
profile 29 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 3 5]
profile 30 needs these types of habitats: [2 3 4 5]
profile 31 needs these types of habitats: [1 2 3 4 5]
```

That is, each turtle has its own profile and can only disperse to the same type of habitat in which it was born. So if at tick 0 it was only born in habitat type 1, it will only be able to disperse in type 1 habitat. The problem is that I am not able to make it so that when the turtles reproduce, they are born in their correct habitat! can anybody help me? Any kind of help I appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Below is a piece of code:

```
extensions [ csv ]

globals [ ValidHabs htypes PatchAvailable ]

turtles-own [ energy reproduction my-patches ]

patches-own [ a-energy metabolism ]

to setup
clear-all
read-habs
reset-ticks 
end

to read-habs  
  set ValidHabs [ ]
  repeat 32 [ set ValidHabs lput [ 0 0 0 0 0 ] ValidHabs ]
  show ValidHabs
  file-close 
  file-open "colony_profiles_habitat_constraints.csv" ;;it reads in the habitat constraints from the "colony_profiles_habitat_constraints.csv" file and builds a list of lists
  let headers file-read-line 
  let profile 0
  while [ not file-at-end?  and profile < 31 ]
  [
    let nextline file-read-line
    let mydata csv:from-row nextline    

    set profile item 0 mydata
    let h1 item 1 mydata
    let h2 item 2 mydata
    let h3 item 3 mydata
    let h4 item 4 mydata
    let h5 item 5 mydata
       

    set htypes [ ]    
    
    if ( h1 > 0 ) [ set htypes lput h1 htypes ]
    if ( h2 > 0 ) [ set htypes lput h2 htypes ]
    if ( h3 > 0 ) [ set htypes lput h3 htypes ]
    if ( h4 > 0 ) [ set htypes lput h4 htypes ]
    if ( h5 > 0 ) [ set htypes lput h5 htypes ]
  ]
end

to go
  Metabolic
end

to Metabolic
ask turtles [
    let z [ a-energy ] of patch-here
    (
      ifelse
      metabolism = 2 [
        set energy energy - 2 + z
        if energy <= 8 [ die ]
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            if energy >= 5 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            if energy >= 10 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            if energy >= 15 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
        )
      ]

      metabolism = 4 [
        set energy energy - 4 + z
        if energy <= 8 [ die ]
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            if energy >= 5 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            if energy >= 10 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            if energy >= 15 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
        )
      ]

      metabolism = 6 [
        set energy energy - 6 + z
        if energy <= 8 [ die ]
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            if energy >= 5 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            if energy >= 10 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            if energy >= 15 [ Dispersion ]
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  ]

end


to Dispersion  
  let available-patch htypes with [ distance myself > 2 and distance myself < 5 and count turtles-here = 0 and not any? other turtles in-radius 2 ]
  set PatchAvailable count available-patch
  if PatchAvailable = 0 [ stop ] 
  let choose-patch one-of available-patch
  let coordx [ pxcor ] of choose-patch
  let coordy [ pycor ] of choose-patch  
  hatch 1 [ setxy coordx coordy ]  
end
```

Comment: I need to see if I understood: each turtle is born on a patch with a specific habitat, and this means that you want all of that turtle's offspring to be born on patches with that same habitat. Is this correct? And if this is correct, where is the habitat information stored for each patch? Can you explain what the `read-habs` procedure does? I cannot quite understand it, and we don't even know what is inside the "colony_profiles_habitat_constraints.csv" file

Comment: I would like to help, too, but we can't run the model with the code that you provided. In order to give us a "Minimal Working Example", you should include e.g. the functions that creates turtles in the setup (otherwise, there are no turtles to hatch from). Also, you could include the result of reading in two lines of "colony_profiles_habitat_constraints.csv", so that we don't have to have that file, but still get an idea what happens.

Comment: Also, since your problem seems to be about the `Disperse` function, we don't need the code of the `Metabolic` function. You could shorten that by writing ```to go ask turtles [Dispersion] end ```

Comment: Another thing I noticed: you can shorten the `Metabolic` function a lot. I think that makes it easier to understand. The great thing about programming is, that you have variables, to encode the numbers. Therefore you don't need that many `ifelse`-statements.
```to Metabolic
  ask turtles 
  [
    let z [ a-energy ] of patch-here
    set energy (energy - metabolism + z)
    if energy <= 8 [ die ]
    if energy >= reproduction [Dispersion]
  ]
end```

Comment: @Lena Yeah I noticed that too but hoped to write that in an answer to have it more readable. But great you pointed it out! Just want to add that it can be shortened even more, as there is no need to create the local variable `z` because it would be used only once, and there is no need to have `of patch-here` when using `a-energy` in any case. In the end it can simply be: `to Metabolic   ask turtles [   set energy (energy - metabolism + a-energy)   if (energy < 9) [die]   if (energy >= reproduction) [Dispersion]   ]   end`

Comment: Thanks Lena e Matteo for the suggestions :)